# "There is no route for the path" in Flow Router on remote server but fine on local

Tags: meteor, flow-router

I use Flow Router in my Meteor app. On the local environment, everything works fine. But when I upload the app to meteor.com server and open it, I get the "There is no route for the path: /" error in console. The route for "/" surely exists and is placed in `client` folder.

What do I do wrong? Is it a known issue?

Comment: try running `meteor --producion` you might be able to reproduce the issue and check browser console for errors

Comment: does the application work after printing this error?

Comment: No, it doesn't. Neither any other route, existing or not, would work. But the initial DOM and styles get loaded correctly.

Comment: @RishatMuhametshin Did you ever find out what was causing this? I'm getting the same error ( just switched from iron router to flowrouter).

Comment: @imarichardson no, and this is super weird. I just created a new app, started with router setup from scratch, copied templates and other client code, and it worked. In 2 hours, the problem has simply been done irrelevant, but not solved.

Answer (score 2):

@RishatMuhametshin  The problem was due to another package that had dependencies on Iron router. For me it was meteor hacks:kadira_debug. That was an older version of the plug in which is now kadira_debug:debug.

It was not intuitive at all to find the package. I literally had to just start commenting out packages one by one to see. Console messages weren't helping and the log output from the terminal showed nothing. This is one of those where instances where I wish there was a development log like I got in rails.

Anyhow the problem was a plug in with dependencies on Iron router.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this problem was caused by "ecmascript" package that was installed with Meteor 1.3.

Comment: I was having `ecmascript` in both original (the one that was having this error) and a new apps, and the latter didn't seem to have any problems caused by it. So, I haven't really found a proper solution, but the one I used just worked for me. Simply create a new app, transfer core part of the codebase, and that's it.